# Loop for change the column - how not mistake $ of column with $i

Tags: bash, loops, awk

I would like to make a loop for change columns in a awk condition. However, the $ symbol is making mistake with the replacement for "i". Any idea how to fix it?

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {2..5}
do
awk '$$i>=10 && $$i<=20' permut1.txt >> out.txt
done
```

input:

```
abc 1 1 2 3 4
bbb 0 1 2 0 1
ccc 1 1 0 2 2
ddd 0 1 3 1 3
fff 15 15 4 15 15
ggg 15 15 15 15 15
```

I want this output:

```
ggg 15 15 15 15 15
```

Comment: Do you want to select lines for which column 2 is between 10 and 20, and then lines for which column 3 is between 10 and 20,  and then lines for which column 4 is between 10 and 20, as your code seems to indicate? Or lines for which all three columns 2, 3 and 4 are between 10 and 20, as your example seems to indicate?

Comment: sorry, i made the change :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In awk, `$` is a prefix operator whose argument must be a non-negative integer. That's quite different from the meaning of the `$` in bash.

The easiest way to pass a variable from bash to awk is to use the `-v var=value` command line option in the awk command:

```
awk -v field=2 '$field >= 10 && $field <= 20' permut1.txt
```

The above will print all lines whose second field is between 10 and 20. You could iterate in bash to do multiple scans of the data, each one scanning a different column:

```
for i in 2 3 4; do
  awk -v field=$i '$field >= 10 && $field <= 20' permut1.txt
done
```

But I suspect that what you are trying to do is to iterate in awk over the fields, and print the lines which satisfy all three tests. Again, the fact that the awk `$` is an operator can make this relatively simple. Another awk feature which simplifies the logic is the `next` command, which reads the next input line and restarts the pattern matching loop. That makes it easy to require that all three tests match:

```
awk '{ for (field = 2; field < 5; ++field) {
         if ($field < 10 || $field > 20) next;
       }
       # We can only get here if none of the fields were outside
       # the range. $0 is the entire line.
       print $0;
     }' permut1.txt
```

Because the default pattern action is precisely `print $0`, we can shorten that script:

```
awk '{ for (field = 2; field < 5; ++field) 
         if ($field < 10 || $field > 20) next;
       }
     } 1' permut1.txt
```

The `1` at the end is a condition which will always be true, with no action (or, in other words, the default action); if the preceding rule doesn't execute the `next` command for any of the fields, then the `1` condition will be executed, and the default action will cause the line to be printed.

Comment: Thank you Rici! Great explanation about the whole process!

Comment: and what can i do if the values of 10 and 20 change for a determined file like:


file -> compare.txt

     `hhh 10 10 10 10 15`


so like the line in this file is around 10 and 15, search for numbers around 10 and 15 in other file